# does this function have max/min?

Tags: derivatives, graphing-functions, maxima-minima

I need to find absolute maximum/minimum of this function (if this function has them),
$$f(x) = x*\sqrt(|log(x)|)$$
domain of the function is: $f: ]0, +\infty[ \to R$
and the domain of its first derivative isn't defined in $x=e$, because when $x = e$ the sign function (i.e derivative of absolute value) isn't defined.Therefore, $$f': ]0, +\infty[\space (without\space e) \to R$$
the first derivative is (I've used product rule): $$1 * \sqrt(|log(x)|) + [(x * sign(log(x)) + 1/x) / (2 * \sqrt(|log(x)|))]  $$
the only thing who can change the sign of the first derivative is the sign function, therefore I have:
$(sign(log(x)) >= 0 \iff log(x) > 1$, so now I know that $f: [1, e[$ is increasing, and $f: ]e, +\infty[$ is increasing too.

$f: ]0, 1]$ is decreasing.

Therefore I have that 1 is a minimum, and the function doesn't have absolute max/absolute min. but this is wrong, because  $e^-1/2$ must be a local maximum.

- EDIT: I think I got where the problem is, in the first derivative, as always.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The minimum of the function is $0$. Note that for any $x$ in $(0,\infty)$, we have $x>0$ and $\sqrt{|\ln x|}\geq 0$, so $f(x)=x\sqrt{|\ln x|}\geq 0\cdot 0=0$. It can be seen that $f$ actually attains the value $0$ at the input $1$, since $\ln(1)=0$, so $0$ is indeed the minimum.

This function does not have an *absolute* maximum because $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=\infty$. However, as you found, it does have a *local* maximum at $1/\sqrt{e}$.

Comment: I don't know why $1/\sqrt(e)$ is a local maximum, because when I compute the first derivative I don't have something that bring me to that result. (I know it's there, because I've read the solution of the exercise).

Comment: Your first derivative is wrong: the $1/x$ term should be multiplied with $x\cdot\text{sgn}(\ln x)$, not added to it. Correcting this issue will yield the correct derivative, namely $\sqrt{|\ln x|}+\frac{\text{sgn}(\ln x)}{2\sqrt{|\ln x|}}$.